# Options for running Python scripts in Azure

Tags: python, azure

I have a Python script that gets data from Google Analytics and puts in into a CSV file. I currently run this script on a local machine but I'd like to run the script in my companies Azure tenant.  What Azure service could / should I use to run this script on a daily schedule?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For your needs, I suggest you use **Web Jobs** in Web Apps Service.

It has two types of Azure Web Jobs for you to choose: 
**Continuous** and **Trigger**.
For your needs, **Trigger** should be adopted.

You could refer to the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-webjobs-resources) for more details.In addition, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) shows how to run tasks in WebJobs.

I created a simple Trigger webjob for your reference.

**Step 1**: I  write a Sample.py  as below:

[image]

I used the python third-party module virtualenv create a isolated python environment and used the `pip install requests` command line to download the libs packages that the requests depend on.

[image]

​
then keep the Sample.py uniformly compressed into a folder with the libs packages dependent on the requests that you rely on.

[image]

**Step 2**: Create webjob in Web app service. Here, I choose Triggered Type and set cron expression `0/5 * * * * *` which means this job will be excuted per 5 seconds.

[image]

you'll see the Web Job list after your successful creation.

**Step 3**: You  could check your running web job's status and logs via the **Logs** button as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's in `activate.bat` (Step 1, second screenshot)?

Comment: @Mike That's the Virtualenv in Python, please see this document:https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/

Comment: Yep, should've checked the path in the screenshot. I thought you had created a custom wrapper for it. Thanks

Comment: It seems that screenhot url is not valid anymore? Woould you edit it?

Comment: Hello! May I ask because the guy asking the question asked that the program generates a .csv file, in that case if he would run it on azure where would he  be able to get the .csv file? Thank you! :D

Comment: Using a Python Runtime stack requires you to use a Linux App instance, which does not currently support WebJobs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create

Comment: @Jay Gong I have searched all over and look like your post could help me run a python script using webjobs. I however cant access your link that explains activate.bat. Are you able to explain what the .batfile is?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the first answer you can also use azure functions with a timer which is basically a script on a cronjob without a full machine and paid by invocation. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a better option than a VM however it seems the Timer trigger - necessary for the script to run on a schedule - doesn't work with Python (only C#, Javascript, and F#)

Comment: Worthwhile to say that Azure Functions now support the Timer Trigger in Python