# Can I host a function in azure which will keep calling a website using python

Tags: python, azure, http, automation

Can I host some code written in python doing following in Azure ?

- 1 - Authenticate to a website using python Requests library
- 2 - Call a web service every 1 - 5 minutes based on configuration
- 2.1 - Maybe use a different proxy after certain time to make this call but yet to decide
- 3 - Add results to Azure Table based on some logic
- 4 - Go to step 2 and repeat until cookie times out

Is this possible using Azure or a overkill ?

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible? It is an overkill for what purpose?

Comment: Because there is something called Azure functions but based on what I read - I think they are supposed to be triggered by some actions whereas what I want needs to be constantly running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience and based on my understanding for your description, I think Azure WebJob is very suitable for your needs. And there was a similar SO thread [Options for running Python scripts in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716757/options-for-running-python-scripts-in-azure/45725327#45725327) which you can refer to do it with Azure WebJob.

Answer (score 0):

Azure functions can be setup to kick off ever X minutes (although that is setup in the function definition and not via configuration file). As of right now this does not work for Python but should in the near future.

In the mean time you can write a C# function that *IS* on a timer that can call your Python HttpTrigger function which performs your needed functionality.