# Python script using webjobs in azure

Tags: python, macos, azure, azure-webjobs

Hello I'm getting an error when uploading a new azure webjob. The error says it cant create the webjob.

I followed this tutorial which I found it in a question that was asked in here. [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160410031124/http://nicholasjackson.github.io/azure/python/python-packages-and-azure-webjobs)

My script is the following:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "site-packages"))
import requests as req

r = req.get('http://my_website.azurewebsites.net/user/cron')
# Development
# r = req.get('http://localhost:5000/user/cron')
print(r.status_code)
```

And the structure of my files is this one 
[image]

If anyone can point out where I made a mistake, I just searched for hours and many questions and tutorials point out this is the proper way to add a library in Azure.

Comment: Hi, would you please post the details about of the error you see.(e.g. a screenshot)

Comment: Hi, any updates? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to the steps as below which I uploaded python script into Webjobs previously.

Step 1 :
Use the **virtualenv** component to create an independent python runtime environment in your system.Please install it first with command `pip install virtualenv`  if you don't have it.

If you installed it successfully ,you could see it in your **python/Scripts** file.

[image]

Step2 : Run the commad to create independent python runtime environment.

[image]

Step 3: Then go into the created directory's **Scripts** folder and activate it (**this step is important , don't miss it**)

[image]

Please **don't close this command window** and use `pip install <your libraryname>` to download external  libraries in this command window.

[image]

Step 4：Keep the Sample.py uniformly compressed into a folder with the libs packages in the **Libs/site-packages** folder  that you rely on.

[image]

Step 5:
Create webjob in Web app service and upload the zip file,then you could execute your Web Job and check the log

[image]

You could also refer to the SO thread :[Options for running Python scripts in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716757/options-for-running-python-scripts-in-azure/45725327#45725327)

Hope it helps you.