# python script on azure web jobs - No module named request

Tags: python, azure

I need to run the python scripts on Azure web jobs but i am getting the below error. I tried all the possible ways like scripts with virtualenv and append the path but none of them is working.

> [10/08/2018 11:27:27 > ca6024: ERR ] ImportError: No module named request

Can you please help me to fix?

The script used in the file is,

```
import urllib.request
print('success')
```

Answer (score 0):

according to

> https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

you can check your python version. it's different between python2 and python3.
in python2.7, use :

```
urllib.urlopen()
```

instead of :

```
urllib.request.urlopen()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below steps which I uploaded Python script into Webjobs previously.

1: Use the **virtualenv** component to create an independent Python runtime environment in your system.If you don't have it, just install it first with command `pip install virtualenv`

If you installed it successfully, you could see it in your **python/Scripts** file.

[image]

2 : Run the command to create independent Python runtime environment.

[image]

3: Then go into the created directory's **Scripts** folder and activate it (**this step is important , don't miss it**)

[image]

Please **don't close this command window** and use `pip install <your libraryname>` to download external  libraries in this command window. Such as `pip install request` for you.

[image]

4：Keep the Sample.py uniformly compressed into a folder with the libs packages in the **Libs/site-packages** folder that you rely on.

[image]

5: Create webjob in Web app service and upload the zip file, then you could execute your Web Job and check the log

[image]

You could also refer to the SO thread :[Options for running Python scripts in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716757/options-for-running-python-scripts-in-azure/45725327#45725327)

Comment: Hi Thanks Jay. I have another issue. One of the packages is .pyd file which is not running and getting an error message. ImportError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time'

Comment: @hariharan Most of `no module named ... ` is due to the loss of package.Did you followed my steps to deploy your webjob task?

Comment: Yes. I have followed the steps but still one of the package saying import module error. it is because of .pyd file on the package. As per my understanding machine should have c++ redistributable file to process the pyd files. Is there any option to install the .exe file on azure web apps?