# Option for running python script in Azure with time trigger

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716757/options-for-running-python-scripts-in-azure/45725327) post about WebJobs and that fits my criteria but i dont see WebJobs option in my portal, I check web-apps section and it only display option for functions app. Azure functions does support python but required Linux box and I only have window so that’s dead-end for me.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Edit (3/31): Actually I found the satisfactory answer from Microsoft support. Adding it here for others. According to support team, WebJobs is currently not supported for App Service on Linux.

Comment: Usually "WebJobs" option should not missing from the section of web app, please refer to this [document](https://azureappservices.blogspot.com/2019/09/azure-webjobs-are-missing-after.html) to check if deleted the "App_Data" folder when deploy the app, it may cause the "WebJobs" option to disappear.

Comment: Indeed this is the issue. Working with support to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi MikeCode, may I know if you have solved this issue ? Can I add this solution to the answer area below ?

Comment: Thanks MikeCode, I have post the solution to the answer area, if it helps your problem, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, it may caused by some mistake during deployment. While deploy to azure, if deleted "App_Data" folder, it will lead to the problem of missing "Webjobs" option from the section of web app. We can refer to this [document](https://azureappservices.blogspot.com/2019/09/azure-webjobs-are-missing-after.html) for further information.