# How to access files uploaded to an Azure Webjob?

Tags: azure, web-services, hosting, azure-webjobs

Some time ago I created with help from a friend an Azure Webjob using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45725327/5838180). I had the job running for a while, then stopped it. I would like now to access/download the files/zip-folder I uploaded back then, but I don't know how to do it. More precisely, I want to get to what is labelled as sample.zip in the image below:

[image]

I had the zip-file also locally saved on my computer, but ever since I have installed a new OS and deleted my old files. I get that far to find the old job and open it (see pics below), but afterwards I am clueless. **Can you walk me through what to do to get to zip-folder?** Tnx

PS: In case it matters, I created at some point an Ubuntu virtual environment for the job (in case terminal commands are needed to get to the zip-folder)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two different ways.

- First Option is to use the Kudu Console to download the content of the WebJob.

  - Open Kudu in App Service -> Click on Debug Console -> access it until your folder opens up and it will let you download the file.

> D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggerType == Continous||TimerTriggered

[image: Kudu Access]

[image: Kudu Console]

- Second through Console in App Service and here is the command for viewing the contents of the WebJob.

> D:\home\site\jobs{​​​​triggerType}​​​​ where triggerType == Continous
> || TimerTriggered

If this doesnt work, you can try this command -

> D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggerType == Continous||TimerTriggered

This way, it will list out the contents of the webjob and files associated in the webjob.
Please see below.

[image: Console]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. For the ease of next viweres I want to point out the correct path to the console: you get into the azure portal -> App Services -> your_job -> advanced tools -> "go" -> Debug console