# Executing Python script in Azure

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-automation

I am new to azure and would need some guidance on running a python script to collect the VM list& count and send it to an email endpoint or slack. I have developed this script, and the required data is being fetched from my laptop by running code.

My question here is, how do I implement this in Azure and send the result out?

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the answer to your question: [Options for running Python scripts in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716757/options-for-running-python-scripts-in-azure)

But the Microsoft documentation seems to have a detailed guide on what you're trying to do [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory).